# Firefox does not take vertical scrollbar width into account when calculating parent div size

Tags: html, css, firefox

```css
.scroll {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: yellow;
  overflow: auto;
  max-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="scroll">
  <div>123456789</div>
  <div>123456789</div>
  <div>123456789</div>
  <div>123456789</div>
  <div>123456789</div>
  <div>123456789</div>
  <div>123456789</div>
</div>
```

**Firefox 79**

When the height of the div overflows, Firefox displays a vertical scrollbar without increasing the width of the div to accommodate it, causing a horizontal scrollbar to show.

[image: Firefox screenshot]

**Chrome 84**

Chrome increases the width of the div as expected and no horizontal scrollbar is shown.

[image: Chrome screenshot]

How can I make Firefox work like Chrome?

Constraints:

- The width of the `scroll` div needs to match its content.
- Overflow needs to be auto.

What I've tried:

- `min-width: 0/auto`
- Flexbox (to get the auto width)
- Various combinations of extra wrapper divs

Comment: my chrome 84 is not giving the result you are showing

Comment: Hmm, I can confirm Chrome's sizing is also a bit off. If you toggle the `position: absolute` style in dev tools it "fixes" itself, which tells me that it's probably a browser bug. But I wasn't experiencing that before.

Comment: See https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=764076.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.scroll {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    display:block;
    background: yellow;
        
    max-height: 100px;
    max-width:auto;
    overflow-y:auto;
    padding-right:18px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="scroll">
  <div>123456789</div>
  <div>123456789</div>
  <div>123456789</div>
  <div>123456789</div>
  <div>123456789</div>
  <div>123456789</div>
  <div>123456789</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but the `padding-right: 18px` will apply even when the vertical scrollbar is not shown.

Comment: Are you able to find a fix?. I got stuck with this. And, i cannot use javascript and need to fix usng CSS only.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
width: fit-content;
```

or

```
width: min-content;
```

or

```
width: max-content;
```

Comment: Why we need add this? . Can you please give explanation?. I changed as you suggested, but, No use.

Comment: This proposed solution does not work.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround that will, depending on your use case, potentially help is setting `scrollbar-gutter: stable;` which will reserve space for the scrollbar (thus adding it to the parent sizing as desired in this question). But this space is always reserved, even when there should be no scrollbar because content isn't overflowing. If you want that space to only show up when the element actually has overflowing content that makes it scroll, unfortunately `scrollbar-gutter: auto;` doesn't help because it runs into the same Firefox bug.

With some cleverness, you might be able to use media queries or [container queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_container_queries) to hack together some conditional way of applying the `scrollbar-gutter: stable;` declaration.

According to the [Firefox tracking bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=764076), this is indeed a deviation from the CSS spec but it's unfortunately not a high-priority issue so we may have to wait years longer for a fix. It's currently prioritized at S3: "(Normal) Blocks non-critical functionality or a work around exists".